# Mavensmate Clean Project takes hours together

Tags: ide, mavensmate, sublime

Is anyone encountering issues while fetching the latest files from salesforce (Clean Project) through the MavensMate-app? It takes 1-2 hours to finish up cleaning. Please provide a solution if anyone has figured it out.

Comment: IntelliJ Idea and illuminated cloud

Comment: Around the time of a new release, I find many aspects of SF become slow for developers: MavensMate, deployment tools, developer console, the whole lot become a real pain. I just give up and use developer console until the new release has stopped slowing things down.